# Css doesn't load at all in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework

this is my index.html

```
 <link href="../../myApp/www/lib/ionic/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and css:

```
body{
  background: darkcyan;
}
```

and here's what i get in console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

what am i missing ? Thanks

Comment: "what am i missing" - the file... Check the pass and fix it.

Comment: now the error is gone , but the custom css not loaded and not effected

Comment: can you upload your project to github and share the link? so we can see your files and if you did the file path correctly?

Comment: If you host the css file in your html-project folder (www) the path would be lib/ionic/css/style.css. If you host the css outside the www folder you would not be able to load it.